# Get value next row based on value current row Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

**Set-up**

I need to obtain the population data for all NUTS3 regions on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUTS_statistical_regions_of_Greece).

I have obtained all URLs per NUTS3 region and will let Selenium loop over them to obtain each region's population number as displayed on its page.

That is to say, for each region I need to get the population displayed in its `infobox geography vcard` element. E.g. for [this region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Athens_(regional_unit)), the population would be `591680`.

---

**Code**

Before writing the loop, I'm trying to obtain the population for one individual region,

```
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcadia'

browser.get(url)

vcard_element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#mw-content-text > div > table.infobox.geography.vcard').find_element_by_xpath('tbody')

for row in vcard_element.find_elements_by_xpath('tr'):

    try:
        if 'Population' in row.find_element_by_xpath('th').text:
            print(row.find_element_by_xpath('th').text)
    except Exception:
        pass
```

---

**Issue**

The code works. That is, it prints the row containing the word 'Population'.

**Question**: How do I tell Selenium to get next row – the row containing the actual population number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `./following::tr[1]` or `./following-sibling::tr[1]`

```
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcadia'
browser=webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

vcard_element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#mw-content-text > div > table.infobox.geography.vcard').find_element_by_xpath('tbody')

for row in vcard_element.find_elements_by_xpath('tr'):

    try:
        if 'Population' in row.find_element_by_xpath('th').text:
            print(row.find_element_by_xpath('th').text)
            print(row.find_element_by_xpath('./following::tr[1]').text) #whole word
            print(row.find_element_by_xpath('./following::tr[1]/td').text) #Only number
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Output on Console:

```
Population (2011)
 • Total 86,685
86,685
```

Answer (score 2):

While you can certainly do this with selenium, I would personally recommend using requests and lxml, as they are much lighter weight than selenium and can get the job done just as well. I found the below to work for a few regions I tested:

```
try:
    response = requests.get(url)

    infocard_rows = html.fromstring(response.content).xpath("//table[@class='infobox geography vcard']/tbody/tr")

except:
    print('Error retrieving information from ' + url)


try:
    population_row = 0
    for i in range(len(infocard_rows)):
        if infocard_rows[i].findtext('th') == 'Population':
            population_row = i+1
            break

    population = infocard_rows[population_row].findtext('td')

except:
    print('Unable to find population')
```

In essence, the html.fromstring().xpath() is getting all of the rows from the `infobox geography vcard` table on the path. The next try-catch then just tries to locate the `th` whose inner text is `Population` and then pulls the text from the next `td` (which is the population number).

Hopefully this is helpful, even if it isn't selenium like you were asking! Usually you'd use Selenium if you want to recreate browser behavior or inspect javascript elements. You can certainly use it here as well though.